# Accessing ActivityMetric fields for Salesforce Contact records via simple-salesforce Python

Tags: python, salesforce, simple-salesforce

I'm trying to access the [ActivityMetrics](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_activitymetric.htm) fields via simple-salesforce in Python.

ActivityMetrics are requested via BaseId and BaseType, however I can't find a way to reference objects via the .get() method this way.

I have also tried a query

```
query = 'SELECT Id FROM ActivityMetric LIMIT 10'
sf.query(query)
```

but get

```
Response content: [{'message': "sObject type 'ActivityMetric' is not supported.", 'errorCode': 'INVALID_TYPE'}]
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you using API version 45 or greater? Are the features active in the target org? Does your user have FLS?

Comment: Hey @DavidReed I'm on API version 46. I'm currently debugging using my admin account (I know I shouldn't) - but FLS shouldn't be an issue. The features are active and visible in the interface.